# How to show each value separately from Array in descending order?

Tags: php, php-7.2

Want to show values separately from an array by writing "Echo". Also for each "Echo" code, the values must go in descending order.
**Here is the Code for Descending values:**

```
<?php
$toplist = array(10, 15, 20, 13, 18, 21, 25);

rsort($toplist);

$length = count($toplist);
for($x = 0; $x < $length; $x++) {
    echo $toplist[$x];
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

**And the Output appears together like this:**

```
25
21
20
18
15
13
10
```

But I want all values separately in descending order by writing each "Echo" code.

**For exaples:**

```
   echo $toplist[$x1];
```

output: 25

```
   echo $toplist[$x2];
```

output: 21

```
   echo $toplist[$x3];
```

output: 20

```
etc. etc...
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. What output are you expecting that you aren't getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the value is reverse-sorted with `rsort`, you can access any value in the array like this:

```
echo $toplist[0];
echo $toplist[1];
echo $toplist[2];
echo $toplist[3];
echo $toplist[4];
echo $toplist[5];
echo $toplist[6];
```